# Selected Row Checkmark color changing

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

we have a table view, with the cell selected being marked by a blue checkmark. The problem is that initially when the table loads, the selected cell will have the check mark in blue color which is what we need like in the below figure 
[image]

Now when we select another row, the selected row check mark changes to white, what could be causing this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Add this if in Bellow `UITableView` Delegate Method Before `return Cell;`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

Hope it Help's you

Comment: Hi, you mean the second row or the first row? I am very new to IOS

Comment: BEfore Return Statement in the above delegate method add that line.

Answer (score 0):

When you select another row, you may deselect the previous row programmaticaly by using
-(void) deselectRowAtIndexPath method of your table

Comment: Acuallay I am deselcting the previous row, the problem is that the newsly selected row has a white checkmark not a blue

Comment: Then, maybe you'll provide some of your code, of your table view controller?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, pm44 answer solved it, thanks for your help again

Answer (score 0):

Just set the tint color of tableview as you need.